# Finding which instance of struct is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct

I have a struct

```
 struct Area{    
  var name = String()
  var image = String()}

var area = [Area]()
```

Then I created two instances of it

```
let cities = [Area(name:"CityA",image:"CityImgA"), Area(name:"CityB",image:"CityImgB"), Area(name:"CityC",image:"CityImgC") ]
let towns = [Area(name:"TownA",image:"TownImgA"), Area(name:"TownB",image:"TownImgB"), Area(name:"TownC",image:"TownImgC")]
```

How to find out if `area` contains `cities` or `towns` and print out location,
I tried this in collectionView I am using for `didSelectItemAt indexPath`

```
if (self.area == self.cities)
{
  Print ("This is a city")
} 
else
{
   Print ("This is a town")
}
```

The compilation fails with the given error,

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[Area]' operands

Comment: You want to compare two arrays of Area structs?

Comment: can you explain more about your logic? What exactly is the criteria for a selected collectionView cell to be a city. And what is the dataSource of your collectionView? cities or towns? or some other array of Area type?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, no I dont want to compare, but to find out whether that selected item is from city oir town.

Comment: "It throws an error". What you mean is the compilation fails with the given error. "Throwing an error" is when a running program uses the `throw` statement.

Comment: @JeremyP, thanks for poinitng out the difference, just edited the questioin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple solutions possible, Simple one would be

**Solution 1:**

Write a extension to array

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(array: [Element]) -> Bool {
        for item in array {
            if !self.contains(item) { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Finally compare your array as

```
    if cities.contains(array: areas) {
        print("cities")
    }
    else {
        print("towm")
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

Second solution would be using `Set` Convert your struct to confirm `Hashable` protocol

```
struct Area : Hashable {

    static func ==(lhs: Area, rhs: Area) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue
    }

    var name = String()
    var image = String()
}
```

Finally convert cities and areas to set and use `isSubset`

```
    let citiesSet = Set(cities)
    let areaSet = Set(areas)

    if areaSet.isSubset(of: citiesSet) {
        print("cities")
    }
    else {
        print("towm")
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Isn't better to XOR the hashValue over both string attributes? Like: `return name.hashValue ^ image.hashValue`. We can't assume two instances are the same just for the hashes matching like how it is now?

Comment: @Alex : I agree :) Idea was just to show OP how to use Set to solve the problem :) OP can modify it suit his needs :) But I agree with your point :)